# Functional need : annotate PDF/PNG/JPEG. (Ionic 3 cordova 8)

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

Functional need : annotate PDF/PNG/JPEG.

Hello, I am new to Ionic and I want to make an application in ionic 3 similar to the applications below:

1-https://flowpaper.com/annotations-html5-pdf-viewer/index.php?ro=html5,html

2-https://web-preview.pspdfkit.com/showcase/bdkqxba

After some research on google I find some solutions:

1-https://github.com/gearit/RadaeePDF-Cordova

2-https://github.com/PSPDFKit/Cordova-Android

3-http://pdfkit.org/index.html

My question is: 
I want to know if anyone has an experience on this kind of tool to annotate a pdf and what is the good solution to solve it.

thank you ;)

Comment: Questions about tools and software are off-topic. Look at [help/on-topic].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! **Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Thus I flagged this question accordingly.